# how to export vpn logging username to csv with powershell?

Tags: powershell, vpn

I use powershell to export vpn logging information, the code like this

```
Get-RemoteAccessConnectionStatistics | Select-Object -Property ClientIPAddress, ClientExternalAddress, ConnectionStartTime, Username, TunnelType
```

The "username" output with {}
https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8sB2.jpg

if I export to csv using this code, the Username show System.String[]

```
Get-RemoteAccessConnectionStatistics | Select-Object -Property ClientIPAddress, ClientExternalAddress, ConnectionStartTime, Username, TunnelType | Export-Csv C:\pvn.csv
```

output result, Username show System.String[]

```
#TYPE Selected.Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance
"ClientIPAddress","ClientExternalAddress","ConnectionStartTime","Username","TunnelType"
"192.168.1.233","123.123.1.4","2021/3/9 ?? 05:31:18","System.String[]","L2tp"
```

I chage Username to {$*.Username} and export to csv, the volume is normal but the title show {$*.Username}

```
Get-RemoteAccessConnectionStatistics | Select-Object -Property ClientIPAddress, ClientExternalAddress, ConnectionStartTime, {$_.Username, TunnelType | Export-Csv C:\pvn.csv
```

output result

```
#TYPE Selected.Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance
"ClientIPAddress","ClientExternalAddress","ConnectionStartTime","$_.Username","TunnelType"
"192.168.1.233","123.123.1.4","2021/3/9 ?? 05:31:18","domain user\tester","L2tp"
```

My question:
1.how to show Username without {}?
2.how to export to csv replace title {$_.Username} with Username?

Comment: Seems like you have to expand the property, try this first: `Get-RemoteAccessConnectionStatistics | Select-Object -Property ClientIPAddress, ClientExternalAddress, ConnectionStartTime, TunnelType,@{Name="UserName";Expression={$_.username}}`

Comment: If the above code doesnt work, assign the command output to a variable and export using a custom object like so:

Comment: `$RemoteAcc = Get-RemoteAccessConnectionStatistics | Select-Object -Property ClientIPAddress, ClientExternalAddress, ConnectionStartTime, Username, TunnelType
$obj=[pscustomobject]@{
        "Client IP Address" = $RemoteAcc.ClientIPAddress
        "Client Ext Address" = $RemoteAcc.ClientExternalAddress
        "Connection Start Time" = $RemoteAcc.ConnectionStartTime
        "User Name" = $RemoteAcc.Username
        "Tunnel Type" = $RemoteAcc.TunnelType
        }
$obj | Format-Table -AutoSize
$obj | Export-Csv -Path C:\pvn.csv -NoTypeInformation

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to convert that property to a string. There are several ways of achieving this:

```
Get-RemoteAccessConnectionStatistics | Select-Object -Property ClientIPAddress, ClientExternalAddress, ConnectionStartTime, @{n='Username';e={($_.Username|Out-String).trim()}}, TunnelType | Export-Csv C:\pvn.csv

Get-RemoteAccessConnectionStatistics | Select-Object -Property ClientIPAddress, ClientExternalAddress, ConnectionStartTime, @{n='Username';e={"$($_.Username)".trim()}}, TunnelType | Export-Csv C:\pvn.csv

#If there are multiple users and you want them on one line joined by commas.
Get-RemoteAccessConnectionStatistics | Select-Object -Property ClientIPAddress, ClientExternalAddress, ConnectionStartTime, @{n='Username';e={$_.Username -join ','}}, TunnelType | Export-Csv C:\pvn.csv
```

Comment: Thank you, and I test your soluation 3, it's lost ")". I add it.     Get-RemoteAccessConnectionStatistics | Select-Object -Property ClientIPAddress, ClientExternalAddress, ConnectionStartTime, @{n='Username';e={($_.Username) -join ','}}, TunnelType | Export-Csv C:\pvn.csv

Comment: You're right, actually for that example `( )` are not needed. I edited my post.